# PHP form reset error after sending the message. How to reset the form after

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

The PHP coding in my webpage does not reset or clear the form fields after it submits the form. but rather when you refresh the page, it sends the same message again. Is there a way I can make it rest or clear the form fields after submitting. Here is my PHP code.

Comment: here is a fiddle to my code  http://jsfiddle.net/mcquaye/BSjF3/

Comment: No offense but first person I know that uses PHP inside JSfiddle o_O

Comment: A little tip: You can't run PHP in jsFiddle, it's a client side sandbox. You want something like http://phpfiddle.org/

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would say without even looking at your code would be to do a redirect in your code back to the original URL once processing has finished correctly.  This is a standard practice for many types of problems, including keeping someone from refreshing a cart checkout page and having a payment submitted twice.  By redirecting to the original page with no parameters being passed, you are essentially clearing out the data yourself.

Answer (score 0):

So in your php success area just use

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('formName').reset();</script>";
```

Where formName is of course the name of your form.